# Add to NSMutableDictionary without replacing similar keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am dynamically populating a NSMutableDictionary with keys that are identical. However doing so replaces the original keys value. What I require is it to be appended and not replacing the existing key. For example, I need a structure like

```
    {
      @"Key" : @"Value1",
      @"Key" : @"Value2",
      @"Key" : @"Value3"
    }
```

I know I could add each NSDictionary that is created to a NSMutableArray but my issue comes because I need the input value to be a NSDictionary.

Currently I have the following which replaces the original value

```
  NSMutableDictionary *ripDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for(NSString *ripId in recievedRips){

        //SOME OTHER CODE

        ripDictionary[@"rip"] = keysAndAttributes;

        [data addObject:ripDictionary];
    }
```

Comment: That's just not how dictionaries work. You can't have what you claim to need. I doubt you actually need that. Explain more about what the data structure is supposed to represent and how you expect to use it. (For example, if a dictionary could do what you want, how would you access the values since the keys are ambiguous? It just doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NSDictionary Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html)

> A key-value pair within a dictionary is called an entry. Each entry consists of one object that represents the key and a second object that is that key’s value. **Within a dictionary, the keys are unique. That is, no two keys in a single dictionary are equal** (as determined by isEqual:).

Perhaps you could modify your code to accept a dictionary like:

```
{
      @"Key" : [
               @"Value1",
               @"Value2",
               @"Value3"
           ]
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on @Frankie's answer, what you seem to need is a dictionary of arrays, so, in ObjC words, an `NSDictionary` made of `NSString` keys and `NSMutableArray` values. Rework your code to conform to this pattern and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single unique key per dictionary, so if you want multiple values associated with it then you would add those values to an array associated with the key.

```
if([aDictionary objectForKey:@"key"] != nil){
  aDictionary[@"key"] = @[aDictionary[@"key"], bDictionary[@"key"]];
}else{
  aDictionary[@"key"] = bDictionary[@"key"];
  //OR make all aDictionary values array by default with a single value
  //but you get the point
}
```